# Integration with okta SSO

Tags: okta, okta-api

Which is the best way to use okta SSO. We want to integrate okta with our ruby web application. Which way will be best from the given below?

1. SWA
2. SAML
3. OpenID Connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use [this gem](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) to integrate my Rails app. I believe SAML the best.